# Does a constant-volume continuous deformation imply the existence of a volume-preserving continuous deformation?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, geometric-measure-theory

For measurable ${\bf A} \subset R^{n}$, let $\mu({\bf A})$ be the $n$-dimensional measure of $\bf A$.

Let ${\bf B} \subset R^{n}$ be homeomorphic to the closed unit ball. Let $\Gamma:{\bf B} \times [0,1] \mapsto R^{n}$ be a continuous function such that $\Gamma(\cdot,0)$ is the identity; and for all $t \in [0,1]$, $\Gamma(\cdot,t)$ is a homeomorphism, and $\mu(\Gamma({\bf B},t)) = \mu({\bf B})$.

Does there exist a continuous function $\Phi:{\bf B} \times [0,1] \mapsto R^{n}$ such that $\Phi(\cdot,0)$ is the identity, and for all $t \in [0,1]$, $\Phi(\cdot,t)$ is a homeomorphism, $\Phi({\bf B},t) = \Gamma({\bf B},t)$ and for all measurable ${\bf A} \subset \bf B$, $\mu(\Phi({\bf A},t)) = \mu({\bf A})$?

That is, $\Gamma$ preserves the overall volume of $\bf B$ but may change the volume of subsets. Can you change $\Gamma$ into a $\Phi$ that has the same overall image but preserves the volume of every subset?

I'm chiefly interested in $n=2$ and $n=3$.

Comment: It seems the hypothesis are not enough, because there are injective curves with positive measure, for example the [Osgood curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgood_curve). So using an ambient isotopy from the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to a closed curve of measure $>0$ you can build a counterexample for $n=2$. Btw is there a reference in english for the fact that any two homotopic simple closed curves in a surface are ambient isotopic? The usual reference is Baer, and I haven´t found that exact result in $\textit{A primer on Mapping Class Groups}$, by Farb and Margalit.